# C# File being used by another process

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I am trying to write a log file, but it constantly says "File being used by another process". Here's my code:

```
//_logFile = "system.log"
if(!File.Exists(Path.Combine("logs", _logFile)))
        {
            File.Create(Path.Combine("logs", _logFile)).Close();
            sw = File.AppendText(Path.Combine("logs", _logFile));
        }
        else
        {
            sw = File.AppendText(Path.Combine("logs", _logFile));
        }
```

When I run it, it points to the `File.Create(Path.Combine("logs", _logFile)).Close()` line and gives me the error.

**Edit:**
I changed `if(!File.Exists(_logFile))` to `if(!File.Exists(Path.Combine("logs", _logFile)))` but I still get the same error.

Comment: You don't need `File.Create` You create a file and never close it with this code...

Comment: Your `File.Exists` isn't checking the same path as the one you are creating the file on... `_logFile` vs `Path.Combine("logs", _logFile)`

Comment: @NathanA I edited my question, I still get the same error.

Comment: This may be stupid, but do you have the relevant file open in other programs (e.g. notepad)?

Comment: We need more code.  Where are you closing/disposing your `sw` stream, if at all?

Comment: And I have to agree with @Eser.  Why call `Create` at all?  `File.AppendText` does the work of creating the file if it doesn't exist: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: And what's with the `Path.Combine("logs", _logFile)` over and over - didn't believe it the first time?

Comment: @NathanA if I remove the File.Create I still get the same error. "The process cannot access the file 'logs/system.log' because it is being used by another process.

Comment: So it goes back to my previous question... Where are you disposing/closing it?  How many times does this code get executed? If you step through your code, does it happen during the first call, or after the first call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't need access to this stream outside the context of this method,  I'd refactor your code to this:

```
var filePath = Path.Combine("logs", _logFile);

using (var sw = File.AppendText(filePath))
{
    //Do whatever writing to stream I want.
    sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": test log entry");
}
```

This way, no matter what happens inside the `using` block, you know the file will be closed so you can use it again later.

Note that `File.AppendText` will create the file if it doesn't already exist, so `File.Create` is not needed.